# Can't not check button title from programmatically DropDown button

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in Swift and my english is not very well

The question is i build a dropdown view from this tutorial

youtube: https://youtu.be/22zu-OTS-3M
github: https://github.com/Archetapp/Drop-Down-Menu

He programmatically create a fantastic dropdown view without storyboard

the code run very good on my Xcode

but when I went to check the title with the button

I never get it.

this my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate

      override func viewDidLoad() 
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let typeBTN = dropDownBtn()
         self.view.addSubview(typeBTN)
         typeBTN.setTitle("animal", for: .normal)
         typeBTN.dropView.dropDownOptions = ["dog", "cat", "cow", "boy"]


 // ....

protocol dropDownProtocol {
    func dropDownPressed(string: String)
}

class dropDownBtn: UIButton, dropDownProtocol {

    func dropDownPressed(string: String) {
        self.setTitle(string, for: .normal)
        self.dismissDropDown()
    }

    var dropView = dropDownView()
    var height = NSLayoutConstraint()



    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

        dropView = dropDownView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        dropView.delegate = self
        dropView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        self.superview?.addSubview(dropView)
        self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(dropView)
        dropView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        dropView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        dropView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        height = dropView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
    }

    var isOpen = false

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if isOpen == false {
            isOpen = true
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
            if self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height > 150 {
                self.height.constant = 170
            } else {
                self.height.constant = self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height
            }
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.dropView.center.y += self.dropView.frame.height / 2
            }, completion: nil)

        }else{ dismissDropDown() }
    }

    func dismissDropDown() {
        isOpen = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
        self.height.constant = 0
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
            self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)   
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class dropDownView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { 

    var dropDownOptions = [String]()
    var tableView = UITableView()
    var delegate: dropDownProtocol!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true


    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return dropDownOptions.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = dropDownOptions[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        self.delegate.dropDownPressed(string: dropDownOptions[indexPath.row])

        print(dropDownOptions[indexPath.row])
```

I have tried a lot to check when button title change. like this

```
 print(typeBTN.currentTitle!)
 print(typeBTN.titleLabel?.text! )
 print(typeBTN.title(for: .normal))
 //I get nothing when i pressed dropdown menu options?
```

because I want to do this

```
if typeBTN.currentTitle == "dog" {
        //show some date at my mapview
    }
```

but when I click the "dog" of dropdown menu

it never work

can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Delegation pattern to notify the title changes to your view controller.

Add the protocol:

```
protocol DropDownButtonDelegate: AnyObject {
    func titleDidChange(_ newTitle: String)
}
```

Add in your DropDownButton class a delegate property:

```
weak var delegate: DropDownButtonDelegate?
```

Then in your dropDownPressed function:

```
func dropDownPressed(string: String) {
    self.setTitle(string, for: .normal)
    self.dismissDropDown()
    delegate?.titleDidChange(string)
}
```

And finally in your view controller implement the DropDownButtonDelegate:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let typeBTN = dropDownBtn()
      self.view.addSubview(typeBTN)
      typeBTN.delegate = self 
      typeBTN.setTitle("animal", for: .normal)
      typeBTN.dropView.dropDownOptions = ["dog", "cat", "cow", "boy"]
    }
}

extension ViewController: DropDownButtonDelegate {
    func titleDidChange(_ newTitle: String) {
        print(newTitle)
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry I do that. but it didn't print new Title 
Can you give me more point? or check the code for me again?
thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Bruce! Have you added `typeBTN.delegate = self` in the viewDidLoad function of your ViewController?

Comment: Hi Francesco Deliro. Oh~you are right.I miss that. Now print(newTitle) is print title when title change. Can i ask one more question? I try to use this function to do set action like this `if typeBTN.currentTitle == "dog" {
        //show some date at my mapview
    }` but i have no idea how to get it

Comment: If I have understood your question, you can do the same using newTitle because it represents your typeBTN current title, so: `if newTitle == "dog"` then do your action.

Comment: I cat't call newTitle  in viewDidLoad. Did i miss some thing?
by the way i already vote your answer but  it's show `Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded,...`

Comment: Ah I see, but when the view is loaded you have a default title ("animal"), so, if you want to update your UI when the title changes, the delegate function where you got the newTitle is the right place. Thank for the vote, you can also mark the answer as the right one if this solved your question :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it !!How stupid I am . Hope you have a great day too.

Comment: You are welcome, happy to help! And don’t say you are stupid :) everyone of us just needs to gain experience. Have a nice day!